# Java parameter between classes

Tags: java

I have the  Class bellow (Java, and I´m not a Java programmer... I´m an old PLC programmer!):

```
public class Valor {

 public  double variavel;
   public Valor(double v1){
           this.variavel=v1;
                 System.out.println("Test" + " " + this.variavel);

 } }
```

This variable v1 coming from another Class.. I want to use this (this.varavel) v1 in another Class at this point (marked with @@):

```
public class RandomWalk implements Runnable
{      
    public void run()
{
    long currentTime = 0;
    long nextTime = 0;

    Random rand = new Random(50);
    double series0 = 32;
    double series1 = 63;
    double upperLimit = 94;
    double scaleFactor = Math.sqrt(interval * 0.1);

    // Variables to keep track of the timing
    long timer = System.nanoTime();

    while (!stopThread)
    {
        // Compute the next data value
        currentTime = (System.nanoTime() - timer) / 1000000;

                     double p = currentTime / 1000.0 * 4;                         
                     series0 = 20 + Math.cos(p * 2.2) * 10 + 1 / (Math.cos(p) * Math.cos(p) + 0.01);

             series1 =  **@@Valor.variavel;**

        }   }}
```

I´m not sure if the syntax and structure are ok...
In this part of the program (System.out.println("Test" + " " + this.variavel);)
I have the real value of the variable but when I´m call the variable in another Class/Method (public class RandomWalk implements Runnable{ public void run())

I have series1=0 (this variable is always =0).
I really don´t know how to access this variable... If you can help me and be specific I will be very tankful!

Many Thanks!

Comment: Well, a few things.  First thing you need, is a reference to the an instance of `Valor` within your `RandomWalk` class, so you're going to need to pass that in some how.  Next, since you're accessing the variable across multi thread boundaries, `variavel` should be marked as `volatile`, otherwise you run the risk of dirty reads

Comment: Also remember, the instance of `Valor` that `RandomWalk` is using MUST be the same instance of `Valor` that the rest of your code is manipulating

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a variable from another class you must do one of two things, either create a new instance of Valor and store it as a variable inside of RandomWalk or turn variavel into a static variable. In your current implementation of Valor I would recommend turning variavel into a static variable.

To turn variavel into a static variable you simply need to add "static" between public and double in the declaration of variavel. However you would no longer be able to use the class constructor of Valor to set variavel and the code would instead look something like this.

```
public class Valor {

public static double variavel;

public static void setVariavel(double newVariavel){
    variavel = newVariavel;
}
```

And after this you can keep RandomWalk as is.

However if you wish to have multiple instances of Valor you would instead leave Valor as it is in its current state and instead change RandomWalk to create and instance of Valor then access the variable variavel inside of that instance making RandomWalk look like this

```
public class RandomWalk implements Runnable {     

    public void run() {
        long currentTime = 0;
        long nextTime = 0;

        Random rand = new Random(50);
        double series0 = 32;
        double series1 = 63;
        double upperLimit = 94;
        double scaleFactor = Math.sqrt(interval * 0.1);
        Valor valorVariavel = new Valor(0/*or whatever value you want variavel to be*/);

        // Variables to keep track of the timing
        long timer = System.nanoTime();

        while (!stopThread) {

            // Compute the next data value
            currentTime = (System.nanoTime() - timer) / 1000000;

            double p = currentTime / 1000.0 * 4;                         
            series0 = 20 + Math.cos(p * 2.2) * 10 + 1 / (Math.cos(p) * Math.cos(p) + 0.01);

            series1 = valorVariavel.variavel;

        }   
    }
}
```